# Tomcat Server Maximum Heap size (-Xmx Value ) is changed while Tomcat is Running?

Tags: java, tomcat

Initially, my Tomcat is Started wit hsome Xmx Value. But it is changing with in 5 mins. But My Tomcat is running with heavy Load.? Is it possible OS can reduce/ increase Xmx Value dynamically?

Comment: Your webapp is eating memory. Run a profiler to investigate memory leaks/eaters and fix it accordingly.

Comment: Use [jvisualvm](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html). It comes with your JDK.

Answer (score 3):

Your -Xmx, your MAX heap will not grow. Your CURRENT heap may grow.

For example...

You start with a -Xmx of 1g.

App starts with a heap of 256m. It may slowly grow (depending on load etc.) to 1g, but it should never pass 1g. If it needs more than 1g of memory it will crash.

Answer (score 0):

```
Is it possible OS can reduce/ increase Xmx Value dynamically?
```

No

OS is not the problem, probably is your app as BalusC suggested